# Apple Pages: Extract 'Style' of a paragraph via AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript

Is it possible to extract the style name (e.g. 'Body', 'Heading', 'Footnote' etc.) of a given paragraph from Apple's pages app via AppleScript?

There's nothing in the Pages AppleScript dictionary, but maybe I'm overlooking something?

Comment: I don't think that the styles are accessible to applescript, only basic font formatting (e.g. font: Cartier Book, size: 11 point, color: red).